# When a program is loaded by the OS into memory from the file system, how does the operating system know how big the program is?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

When a program is loaded by the OS into memory from the file system,  how does the operating system know how big the program is?

Does it just page in one page from the file system at a time?
Or is there some sort of hardware or software indicator so that the OS knows how big the program is?

Comment: What exactly do you mean `how big`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'program', the size of the machine code (.text) or the all the exe segments?

Comment: What I'm basically asking (I think) is when a program is made into a process,  how does the OS know how much memory to allocate to the process?

The .exe you click is just one file of many.

Comment: It will typically parse some header that contains information about the program, including sizes of executable sections, and proceed accordingly. Whether it maps the whole thing into memory or not is a detail - you can proceed as if it had since the system will transparently page anything that's missing into memory when it is needed.

Comment: Ah just read your comment! Thanks Nik! 

So the paging is where I'm having the issue. 

Any good links on how file system paging works?

(NOT swap paging, unless they're the same thing)

Edited again for briefness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a header at the beginning of the executable that lays out the sections of the executable for the OS.  On Linux this is generally the ["ELF" format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), on Windows its a different format, but the idea is the same.

Sections in the executable may be copied directly into memory, or may be loaded/paged in on-demand.  Some sections may be virtual (e.g., the layout says "I need 8MB of zero'd memory", but the file doesn't actually contain 8MB of zeros).  Sections may be moved around in memory, or may be loaded at a fixed location in memory.

Only the initial executable is loaded this way by the OS.  Any other files (or dynamically linked libraries, etc) are indirectly loaded by the OS (the app just asks for memory, asks for bits of files to be copied into that memory, and then jumps into that code).